# ¿Cómo mostrar un Splash al cargar un Webview, con Android?

Tags: java, android

Yo tenía un código donde podía mostrar un Splash antes de que se cargase el webview de mi página en la app. Sin embargo, no podía loguearme con facebook debido a sus pop-ups. A pesar de esto, encontré un código salvador que hizo que funcionase, aunque tuve que sacar una clase llamada *MyAppWebViewClient* para colocar el *UriWebViewClient* y ahora no sé cómo ni dónde colocar el Splash. ¿Alguien puede ayudarme? Estos son los archivos:

main.activity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

/* URL saved to be loaded after fb login */
private static final String target_url="http://www.chapatelo.com.ar/";
private static final String target_url_prefix="www.chapatelo.com.ar";
private Context mContext;
private WebView mWebview;
private WebView mWebviewPop;
private FrameLayout mContainer;
private long mLastBackPressTime = 0;
private Toast mToast;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // final View controlsView =
    // findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
    mWebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    //mWebviewPop = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewPop);
    mContainer = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.webview_relative);
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebview.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    webSettings.setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(new UriChromeClient());
    mWebview.loadUrl(target_url);

    mContext=this.getApplicationContext();

}


private class UriWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        String host = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
        //Log.d("shouldOverrideUrlLoading", url);
        if (host.equals(target_url_prefix))
        {
            // This is my web site, so do not override; let my WebView load
            // the page
            if(mWebviewPop!=null){
                mWebviewPop.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mContainer.removeView(mWebviewPop);
                mWebviewPop=null;
            }
            return false;
        }

        if(host.equals("m.facebook.com") || host.equals("www.facebook.com")){
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch
        // another Activity that handles URLs
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
                                   SslError error) {
        Log.d("onReceivedSslError", "onReceivedSslError");
        //super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
    }
}

class UriChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateWindow(WebView view, boolean isDialog,
                                  boolean isUserGesture, Message resultMsg) {
        mWebviewPop = new WebView(mContext);
        mWebviewPop.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        mWebviewPop.setWebViewClient(new UriWebViewClient());
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebviewPop.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
        mWebviewPop.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        mContainer.addView(mWebviewPop);
        WebView.WebViewTransport transport = (WebView.WebViewTransport) resultMsg.obj;
        transport.setWebView(mWebviewPop);
        resultMsg.sendToTarget();

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCloseWindow(WebView window) {
        Log.d("onCloseWindow", "called");
    }
}
}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.chapatelo.www.chapatelo_beta.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/webview_relative">

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="641dp"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashLoading1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@mipmap/splash"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Nota: La clase anterior que tenía para ejecutar el Splash antes de que se cargue el webview era la siguiente (MyAppWebViewClient.java):

```
public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){

        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("chapatelo.com.ar")){
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Y así manejaba el Splash (ImageView):

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient(){
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            findViewById(R.id.splashLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

¿Alguien podría indicarme cómo puedo hacer que la *ImageView* aparezca desde que se abra la app hasta que se cargue el WebView y que desaparezca tal y como hacía en el último código que mostré?

Comment: he colocado una respuesta.

Answer (score 3):

Prueba de poner primero el ImageView y después el webview con visibilidad `gone` en tu layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.chapatelo.www.chapatelo_beta.MainActivity"
android:id="@+id/webview_relative">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splashLoading1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:src="@mipmap/splash"
    android:contentDescription="@string/desc"/>

<WebView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="641dp"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:visibility="gone"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para asegurar tu imagen siempre este visible al inicio...

crea un tema dentro de `styles.xml` para tu SplashScreen Actitivy, y define como background tu imagen:

```
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/mi_fondo_splash</item>
  </style>
```

Dentro de tu `AndroidManifest.xml` define el el tema a tu Activity:

```
   <activity android:name=".SplashScreenActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

Con esto aseguras siempre cargar la imagen al inicio.